# Instagram style unique URLs

Tags: url, cakephp

I am developing a CakePHP application which allows for photo uploads. It would be really nice if i could give the user a friendly unique URL of something like instagram does, ie:

`http://example.com/v/157fd` to view their single photo post.

What is the best approach for this, i take it its going to involve CakePHP routing at some point, but has someone got an flow of what would happen when a URL like this is hit and how these unique URLs are formed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the route would be easy with one line (change the controller and action to yours):

> ```
> Router::connect('/v/*', array('controller' => 'photos', 'action' => 'view'));
> ```

You can just use the photo id, or create your own random id. There's also a convenient way in cake to have random id, which is to use [UUID](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1016/Using-UUIDs-as-Primary-Keys)

Comment: Great comment. Is there a way to make a UUID 6 or 8 characters as apposed to the default 36 chars as stated on the link you provided: "A UUID is a 32 byte string separated by four hyphens, for a total of 36 characters."

Comment: the UUID is guaranteed to be unique. You need to create your own functions to generate random id and check for collision if you want it to be 6-8 char long.